# After inserting new data how to reload the page in react-native and i'm using mobx for state management

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-native-flatlist, mobx

I'm using code like this it is not working for me

```
componentWillRecieveProps(nextProps,nextState){
  if(nextProps.navigation.state != this.state){
    //here calling api
   }
}
```

Comment: Can you at-least provide minimum code to understand the issue. This is not at all enough to understand whats going on and why you are facing issue.

Comment: Please elaborate

Answer (score 2):

I think the question should be more elaborative to help to solve your issue. Based on your questions, you may be asking for either -

1. How to reload page if data changes
2. How to reload page if navigation state changes

### How to reload page if data changes

In this case, you no need to add 'componentWillRecieveProps'. You can simply check for a value in render method like this

```
{data.items.length && <ItemLIstCustomComponent />}
```

or

```
{data.items.length ? <ItemLIstCustomComponent /> : <EmptyMessageComponent />}
```

You can look into [conditional rendering](https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html) in react-native.
If the re-render is not happening still? Then your way of updating state/data is not correct. Make sure you make copy of object and update the existing one.

To understand this, read about mutable objects and react shallow-check for re-rendering. Or may be [this](https://mobx.js.org/best/react.html) will help

### How to reload page if navigation state changes

I don't think it is good practice to call another API or do any state change related thing in `componentWillRecieveProps`. You can create a new Screen on which you navigate and call API in `componentDidMount`.
You can try [React navigation](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/getting-started) if you are not using any navigation library.